# C# custom property editor

Tags: c#, properties

I have the following custom property in my code:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> ServiceIdList
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Dictionary<int, string>)(GetValue(LoadSubscriptionList.ServiceIdListProperty)));
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LoadSubscriptionList.ServiceIdListProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

But the property editor for this (String Collection Editor) comes up disabled. Do I have to implement a custom UITypeEditor or can the getters and setters be improved as to provide 'hints' to the editor as to what types can be in an entry?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: no, it's a Windows Workflow Foundation one

Comment: How were you planning on setting the Key values?  Should this be a `List<string>` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this thread that may be of help to you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f2ecec70-4e44-43bb-8a09-feb8a55b365c

It appears that generic `Dictionary` objects do not have an editor that works with them.  You'd have to derive from the `CollectionEditor` and override a few functions, such as `CreateNewItemTypes`.